# PHP ImageMagick Creating Animated GIF is Keeping Old Frames

Tags: php, imagemagick, animated-gif

My GIF created by ImageMagick is keeping the previous frames while playing the next frames. I want it to only show the frame it's currently on.

```php
$GIF = new Imagick();
$GIF->setFormat("gif");

$frame = new Imagick();
$frame->readImageBlob($frames[1]);
$frame->setImageDelay(10);
$GIF->addImage($frame);

$frame = new Imagick();
$frame->readImageBlob($frames[2]);
$frame->setImageDelay(10);
$GIF->addImage($frame);

$gifblob = $GIF->getImagesBlob();
```

I know I should be doing that in a loop but either way. Is there any way to stop the previous frame from staying in the animation? I want each image added to the GIF to replace the previous frame.

Edit: Issue was I was missing - $GIF->setImageDispose(2); (Thanks fmw42)

Comment: You need to set the dispose method before reading the frames. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagedispose.php

Comment: See also https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#dispose